# Time Complexity of Printing a Graph in Adjacency List Representation

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, time-complexity, complexity-theory

What is the order of growth of the running time of the following code if the graph uses an adjacency-list representation, where V is the number of vertices, and E is the total number of edges?

```java
// G.V() returns number of vertices, G is the graph. 
for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
    for (w : G.adj(v)) {
        System.out.println(v + "-" + w); 
    }
}
```

Why is the time complexity of the above code Theta(V+E), where V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges?

I believe that if we let printing be the cost function, then it should be Theta(sum of degrees of each v) = Theta(2E)  = Theta(E) because we enter the inner loop deg(v) times for vertex v.

Comment: You examine each vertex *and* each edge; your graph might not contain any edge, but you'd still go over all vertices, which is why both quantities would appear in the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> if we let printing be the cost function, then

Using such assumption, yes, there will be `Theta(E)` `println` calls.

However, generally the execution time does not depend only on printing, but also on other instructions such as `v++`, there will be `Theta(V+E)` of them all.

Comment: So is your cost function - printing + incrementing?

Comment: I just referred to Algorithms Part 1 and there the authors suggest that the cost model should be from the inner loop on Page 184.

Comment: @GoldCredential I'm not sure which book you refer to (Sedgewick and Wayne?), and which edition of it (note that Page 184 may refer to something else depending on the edition of a book). Could you please provide the relevant fragment which I could relate to?

Comment: Sorry @ciamej, could you include your cost function in your answer?